# parent process and child process relationship in Linux bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, process, pid

i have a question about linux process, and i can not figure it out.
This problem came from the book “Advanced Bash Script”, code is here: (I have simplified it)

```
#! /bin/bash
# spawn.sh
sleep 1
sh $0   # fork a child process here and into infinite loop

exit 0  # the script will never come here
```

when i run **./spawn.sh** in the shell, the process will be stuck there, and there will be a lot of "sh spawn.sh" processes there after a while.
i think the relationship among processes now is like:

./spawn.sh process(pid: 10000) ---> child process(pid: 10001) ---> child process(pid:1002) --->child process(pid:1003) ---> and so on

when i push Control-C in the Shell, the parent process is over, **and all its child processes are over too**. this is where i can not understand. why all child processed perish ? i think the relationship among processes should be like:

init(pid: 1) ---> child process(pid: 10001) ---> child process(pid:1002) --->child process(pid:1003) ---> and so on

But the fact is that **as if** parent process sends a signal to it child process when it is over, thus cause all child processes perish one by one. Is this normal or a feature of shell script?

thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when i push Control-C in the Shell, the parent process is over, and
>   all its child processes are over too. this is where i can not
>   understand. why all child processed perish

When you hit Ctrl-C, SIGINT is sent not only to the parent process but to the entire process group. What this means is that all three processes get a SIGINT, so they die. To see this in action, add a

```
trap "process $$ exiting" INT
```

A quick way to see that children don't react to their parents' demise is to have a script spawn a single child and then kill the parent.

Comment: thank you very much! and i still wonder why "the SIGINT will be sent to the entire process group"? is this how shell script is implemented or is it a common implementation in Linux?

Comment: @ruanhao As far as I know all Unices do this. It's not the shell that sends the signal, it's the terminal driver.

Comment: i found one thing: when i push Control-C, all processes will be killed. but when i input 'kill -2 <parent-process-pid>' in another shell, there is no effect, no process is killed. when i use SIGKILL(9) to kill the parent process, it will kill only the parent process with all child processes live there. Is Control-C not the same as 'kill -2'? (i do these tests on OSX)

Comment: @ruanhao That's a result of not using the terminal driver to send the signal, as @cnicutar mentioned. Using `kill` bypasses the logic that the terminal driver follows when it detects `control-C`...

Answer (score 0):

Control-C is killing the most recent child, not the original shell. When `sh $0` exits, the next line of code causes the current shell to exit as well, which causes a cascade of completed processes all the way back to the original parent.

Answer (score 0):

i think i know the answer now. it is because that Control-C will send SIGINT to not only the shell script process, but also its sub processes. Since these processes do not trap SIGINT, so they are over.
Command **kill -2**  is not the same as Ctrl-C, for detail, see this: http://ajhaupt.blogspot.com/2011/01/whats-difference-between-ctrl-c-and.html
And thank you all guys help me :)

Comment: i have something to add. **if only** the parent process is over, then all child processes will be sent SIGINT. you can observe this by insert `trap '' 2` in parent process. thus parent process will ignore SIGINT and all its child procs will be still there.